# How to pass a list, vector or array as argument in invokeMethod function

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, vector, qml

Here is the documentation for the [invokeMethod function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod).

So if I pass a string or QString type as argument, then it works. But is it possible to pass a list, vector or array of QString as argument?

P.S: The argument has to be a type of QGenericArgument and I have to use the [Q_ARG](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#Q_ARG) macro to create the QGenericArgument object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html). You can pass a QVariantList and then read the list in your QML file.

**C++**

```
QVariantList list;
list << 10 << QColor(Qt::green) << "bottles";


QMetaObject::invokeMethod(view.rootObject(), "readValues",
        Q_ARG(QVariant, QVariant::fromValue(list)));
```

**QML:**

```
 function readValues(anArray) {
    for (var i=0; i<anArray.length; i++)
        console.log("Array item:", anArray[i])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You must register the type so that Qt can handle it correctly.

On how to register a type see
[qRegisterMetaType](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1) and
[Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)

Qt types are already registered. So passing e.g. a QStringlist via Q_ARG shouldn't be a problem at all.

```
QString retVal;
QStringList values = QStringList() << "aaa" << "bb" << "cccc";
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "findLongest", Qt::DirectConnection,
                      Q_RETURN_ARG(QString, retVal),
                      Q_ARG(QStringList , values));
```

Comment: Thanks invokeMethod function worked! And how do I process the QStringList values in the findLongest function? How can I let the function know, that it is a type of QStringList (in QML)?

Comment: @OnurA I haven't worked with QML yet. Usually the invoked method is `invokable` or a slot. In this example it would most probably look somehow like this: `QString findLongest(QStringList list);`